# Explode numbers as string

Tags: php, explode

I have a string containing several ids concatenated by `_`

I need to split them into an array to further use them but PHP always parses them as integer and rounds them which makes the ids unusable.

How can I split the string into an array of strings?

This is some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
$str = "version_52466436643546949646431_658465546513164146498646444346_4646464616416464649846465412113";

$explode = explode('_',$str);
print_r($explode); //the individual ids are rounded now
```

How can I split this so PHP takes the numbers as strings instead of integers?

Comment: I tried this exact code and it did not round anything. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: what is wrong with this ?`array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "version" [1]=> string(23) "52466436643546949646431" [2]=> string(30) "658465546513164146498646444346" [3]=> string(31) "4646464616416464649846465412113" } `

Comment: I think your DB changes the ID not PHP, for example: you might set `int(11)` but the id here is `int(30)`!

Comment: What you mean they are rounded? Could you share the ouput of your `print_r($explode)`?

Comment: @akam: the `(30)` v.s. `(11)` is simply a display hint to mysql, "use THIS many digits to display the number. It has NOTHING to do with how large a number can be stored in the field. `int(1)` v.s `int(9999)` is **STILL** a 4-byte integer internally. OP would need a `bigint` instead.

Comment: @MarcB:thanks for this note, I need to read mysql data type again, but I think I am right about the approach, also, I inserted to my local db only `2147483647` inserted from `658465546513164146498646444346`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the split you're after this may work....I'm very new to PHP though :)

```
function numStr($str, $count) {

     $words = explode("_", $str);
     $chunk = array_chunk($words, $count);
};

$str = "version_52466436643546949646431_658465546513164146498646444346_4646464616416464649846465412113";
$count = 23;
```

Adding some further code to eliminate the '_' & 'version' etc...